# Gradle project refresh error : (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build my first android app using Android Studio. Unfortunately, every time I open my project, try to run it or gradle assemble it I get the following error :

```
Gradle 'MalipoBatteryAlarm' project refresh failed:
C:\Users\wickedQuasar\.gradle\daemon\1.10\daemon-6128.out.log
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

What file or directory is causing the problem is unclear. I used to overcome this error by rebuilding my project, changing access rights to username.gradle folder or switching b/w using default and customizable gradle wrappers. From last two days nothing seems to fix it and I'm totally stuck. I've also tried this : [Gradle: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168156/gradle-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect) but it didn't fix it.

I've wasted tens of productive hours of my life trying to fix it so any help would be appreciated. From my research I found that this error is usually caused by "unnacceptable characters" in file names. i can't seem to find the cause in my case though.

I'm using a 32bit win 7 machine with Android Studio 0.5.5. My java env variables are set properly.

Update : The command

```
gradlew build --stacktrace
```

returns BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but not in the IDE...

Gradle build file for project root :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Module gradle build file :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: It seems that all gradle terminal tasks are run with success but same "in-built" IDE tasks fail with the above error. Also, my gradle console window in AS doesn't show any output whatsoever.

Comment: Please attach the contents of your build files to your question.

Comment: Added them to my question. Although these are default configs..

Comment: Yeah, those are standard. I thought perhaps there was something custom in there. The working directory isn't the same when you run in the IDE vs. the command-line, so I thought there might be a possibility of something strange going on with that.

Comment: The error is shown in the dialog window, it have been reported by some intermediate task[file]. Is there any way to track its source....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround : Switched to commandline now. Assembling using gradle commandline and installing/monitoring using adb and ddms. Everything is dramatically fast now and works like a charm on a dual monitor setup. IDE is still showing the error though...