# Gradle build failing with Java IOException

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, java-io

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to execute the gradle.bat file, or any gradle command for that matter (eg. gradle -version).

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Gradle Version: 4.10.2

JDK: "1.8.0_261"

OS: Windows 10 (x64)

What could have possibly gone wrong?

---

P.S: I have also tried the same with a newer gradle version (6.6.1). It generated a similar error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at org.gradle.internal.FileUtils.canonicalize(FileUtils.java:204)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildLayoutParameters.findGradleUserHomeDir(BuildLayoutParameters.java:51)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildLayoutParameters.<init>(BuildLayoutParameters.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.converter.BuildLayoutConverter.defaultValues(BuildLayoutConverter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
        at org.gradle.internal.FileUtils.canonicalize(FileUtils.java:202)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: See if anything here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967831/org-gradle-api-uncheckedioexception-failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input.

Comment: @MateMrše It doesn't help much

Comment: Is your user home on a network share? If so, what is the path? If not, have you set any of the Gradle build properties like `gradle.user.home`?

Comment: Check out this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168156/gradle-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem simply by adding the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable under ***User Variables*** instead of ***System Variables***.