# app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error. java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: android, ionic5

I am working on Ionic 5 Project and getting an error while building for Android using command "cordova build android" [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRXOL.png). Is there any solution for this? I have setup JAVA_HOME and Path in Environment since I am using Windows 10. If any other details required please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168156/gradle-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect

Comment: I tried those answers also. Still getting same error.